# Is there a way to replace anomalies with the mean of the two rows between them?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that I'm trying to smooth out the results. Most of the data creates a smooth chart but sometimes I get a random spike. I want to reduce the impact of the spike.

My thought was to take the outlier and just make it the mean of the values between it but I'm struggling and not getting the result I want.

Here's what I'm doing right now:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 1)), columns=list('A'))
def aDetection(inputs):
  median = inputs["A"].median()
  std = inputs["A"].std()
  outliers = (inputs["A"] - median).abs() > std
  print("outliers")
  print(outliers)
  inputs[outliers]["A"] = np.nan #this isn't working.
  inputs[outliers] = np.nan #works but wipes out entire row
  inputs['A'].fillna(median, inplace=True)
  print("modified:")
  print(inputs)
print("original")
print(df)
aDetection(df)


original
    A
0   4
1  86
2  40
3  99
4  97
outliers
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
modified:
      A
0  86.0
1  86.0
2  86.0
3  99.0
4  97.0
```

For one, it seems to change all rows not just the single column. But the bigger problem is all the outliers in my example are using 86. I realize this is because I set the mean for the entire column, but I would like the mean between the previous column with the missing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a **single** column, you can do your task with the following one-liner
(for readability folded into 2 lines):

```
df.A = df.A.mask((df.A - df.A.median()).abs() > df.A.std(),
    pd.concat([df.A.shift(), df.A.shift(-1)], axis=1).mean(axis=1))
```

Details:

- `(df.A - df.A.median()).abs() > df.A.std()` - computes *outliers*.
- `df.A.shift()` - computes a *Series* of **previous** values.
- `df.A.shift(-1)` - computes a *Series* of **following** values.
- `pd.concat(...)` - creates a DataFrame from both the above *Series*.
- `mean(axis=1)` - computes means by rows.
- `mask(...)` - takes original values of *A* column for non-outliers
  and the value from *concat* for outliers.

The result is:

```
      A
0  86.0
1  86.0
2  92.5
3  99.0
4  97.0
```

If you want to apply this mechanism to **all columns** of your DataFrame,
then:

1. Change the above code to a function:

   ```
   def replOutliers(col):
       return col.mask((col - col.median()).abs() > col.std(),
           pd.concat([col.shift(), col.shift(-1)], axis=1).mean(axis=1))
   ```
2. Apply it (to each column):

   ```
   df = df.apply(replOutliers)
   ```

Comment: this is awesome. The explanation is great. thank you